Android app Open Ads violation of rules when using built-in applications
App Open Ads display ads even when the application goes from the background to the foreground after starting internal applications and returning back again. I received a warning that it is a Policy issue - navigation and it must be fixed. It's a bit of a problem, because the system evaluates such a transition not as navigation, but as a transition from the background to the foreground. How do you handle it?
For now, I try to solve it by setting a variable in SharedPreferences every time I go to start an internal application, such as alarm clock, ... and then I evaluate whether yes or not to run appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable
but that needs to be set when starting each internal application, such as displaying FAQs from the Internet, or Privacy Policy from the Internet, ... maybe there is a better sollution.
Shared.allowAppOpenAd = false;
Intent mClockIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS);
mClockIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(mClockIntent);

if (Shared.allowAppOpenAd) {
  appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable(currentActivity);
}else{Shared.allowAppOpenAd = true;}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
